# Excel VBA: Array lookup with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to automate a process for work.  the current process works like this.  I start off with a salary schedule like this:

[image]

Every month I receive a report that looks like this:

[image]

What I have to do is lookup the salary for each employee on the schedule, for each month that they are on the schedule.  I use the "Colleague ID" and the month as my criteria. This is done once a month so for example, next month i'll receive a consolidated report like the one in the picture but with jan, feb, and march payroll. My finished product needs to look like this:

[image]

Obviously, there are multiple ways to accomplish this.  this formula is the method that I've been using lately:

```
{=VLOOKUP($B7&G$6,CHOOSE({1,2},Sheet5!$A:$A&Sheet5!$B:$B,Sheet5!$E:$E),2,0)}
```

This is all fine and good but my examples in the pictures are very small versions of what I'm typically working with.  A lot of times the schedules have over a hundred people on them and the payroll file I receive is several tens of thousands of lines long so this formula can take a bit of time to process.  I know there has to be a more elegant and efficient way to achieve this in VBA with array(s) but I'm not familiar enough with that particular code to accomplish it without assistance.  Also, I'd rather not just convert this formula to a Worksheet Application function just for the sake of automation.  any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Help with what? It sounds like you just want someone to write a bunch of code for you. There are freelance sites for that sort of thing.

Comment: @Jeeped I mean, im not forcing anyone to do anything.  if someone wants to offer assistance, then ill be thankful.  if someone got me started I could probably figure it out on my own.

Comment: What if you just took the monthly report, inserted a column A and set A equal to Colleague ID concatenated with the month? Then the VLookUp could be using just one index?

Comment: `SumIfs` or Pivot Table ?

Comment: @Demetri that's a good Idea but the report is sent from payroll and is locked by management so I would have to maintain my own copy of the file and id have to update it every month.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to retype all of the data that you've sreenshot but I would get rid of your array formula and use a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B).

Comment: @DavidZemens i've tried Pivot Tables before.  if it was just me that was going to be using this, that would be fine.  im making this for other people to use as well and I just know that they'll find a way to screw them up or not refresh the table, etc....  Sumifs is where im headed next I think.

Comment: I guess I concur with everyone else, even though you're not technically summing a bunch of numbers, the sumif should be fine for achieving what you want and be much faster then the array formula.

Comment: SumIfs seems like the easiest way to do it, and if you wanted to make it super easy for other users, you could create a custom function (though you'd have to distribute that in an XLAM or something, probably).

Comment: @Demetri my only problem with Sumifs is that some names appear on the file multiple times within a month because their time is allocated to several clients.  for instance, john doe may appear two times because he's 50% allocated to company A and 50% allocated to company B

Comment: I'm not sure that's an issue with `SumIfs`, if you're using criteria as the date and ID, it should return the sum of all matching rows, right?

Comment: @Demetri but john doe's total salary for the month would appear in the salary column for both lines so i'll end up with his salary multiplied times 2 if i use sumif, correct?

Comment: the vlookup stops at the first instance of a match and that works fine because every instance of an employees name in the file for the month will have the same salary in the salary column

Comment: @DavidZemens im pretty sure if the employee appears 3 times in the file for one month, i'll end up with his/her monthly salary X 3

Comment: Then take the result of `SumIfs` and divide by `CountIf`

Comment: @DavidZemens in the end, will that be quicker than the original array formula though?

Comment: That seems like a question you can probably answer on your own, no?

Comment: Something like this: http://imgur.com/7RXAoQU

Comment: @DavidZemens thanks i'll give it a shot.  im not trying to be spoon fed, just trying to broaden my horizons.

Comment: would this be a situation where I could try and use index and match for multiple criteria?  I know it doesn't work as great in vba as it does as a worksheet formula when you have more than one critera.